# Calling external *.php file in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I wrote a mini php script to determinate if I am logged in into a specific joomla site.

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) 
{
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
}

defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->groups;


if($user->id)
{
    if (isset($groups[7]) or isset($groups[8])) 
    {
        echo $user->username;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }   
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

I uploaded it into the root folder.
If I call it via browser it works perfectly. It returns the username when i'm logged in and returns false when i'm logged out.

But i need to call it from another php which is on a different server:

i call it this way:

```
$siteText= file_get_contents ("http://examplejoomlasite.org/miniphpscript.php");
```

But it returns always false, regardless i'm logged in or out.

any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that file_get_contents is not returning false because the allow_url_fopen option is turned off in the php.ini?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is on in php.ini. if thats the problem it wouldn return false, it would return nothing

Comment: not important right now, but the function would return false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but when you call it from another computer (server in this case), there is no session defined for that connection (usually passed as a cookie), so php starts a new one (with no one logged).

Comment: the site is not hosted on my pc but it works.  it only does not work if I call it from that php file which is hosted on a local xampp server on my computer.

Comment: is there any chance to catch it when I am logged in to joomla?